# how get tasks of Queue

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am using CRM-2011. I have so many queues which have tasks. I want to get tasks of every queue in report. What is sql query to do that.
I want like
Queue Name       Open Task
Test1            47
test2            58
test3            10

If anyone have an idea please share with me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The important factor here is the Queue Item entity. This holds a lookup to the related item (Task in your case) and the Queue it is in, as well as metadata such as when it was created, who is working on it etc). So you need to query this table, joined and filtered by Task status. I can't recall if there is a FilteredView for Queue Items, but there should be. This would have the Queue name in already (the filtered views are de-normalised)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the Download Fetch XML code that CRM is running to display those queues? If you can do that we can piece this back together in SQL to return a report of all tasks from each Queue.